# XSLT check if a particular element is preceeded by a text node (why this does not work)

Tags: xml, xslt

I do not understand why checking whether an element (p in my case) is preceeded by a text node, using the following expression:

`preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]`

does not work properly. Here is an example to illustrate:

**Input**:

```
<div> 
   simply a text node
   <element />
   <p/>
</div>
```

**XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]">
     <br />
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was expecting that the `<br />` does not get inserted because the node immediately preceeding `<p />` is an element, not a text node. However the output is:

```
<div> 
   simply a text node
   <element/>
   <br/>
   <p/>
</div>
```

The same as if I would not have the `<element/>` node. Could someone please point me out to what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the whitespace (line break and spaces for indent) between the original `<br/>` and `<p/>` is its own text() node.

Try adding the following as a child of `xsl:stylesheet`...

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I see the problem now. Your suggestion works very well for this particular example. My only worry is whether this results in any side effects, when working with larger more complex documents?

Comment: Yes, with mixed content, whitespace text nodes might be significant. The other way is to ignore them in the preceding-sibling test: use `preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::text()[normalize-space()='')][1][self::text()]` which checks that the first preceding sibling node that is not a whitespace text node is a text node.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing to check if text() value is null:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text() = '']">
        <br />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think you'd better check the normalized whitespace of the text node: `test="preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[normalize-space() = '']]"`. Just checking for `text() = ''` won't succeed in the OP's example, since the text() node between `<element>` and `<p>` still consists of whitespace.

Comment: well, using normalize-space didn't work the expected way. With normalize-space() you should check for a space(' '), instead.

Comment: This does not work properly, because it's saying: insert a `<br />` only if the immediately preceding element is null text, which is not what I'm trying to achieve. I want to insert a `<br />` only if the preceding element is a text node that is not just white space. However this inspired me to the following change in th test predicate: `preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][normalize-space() != '']` which seems to does what I'm looking for...

Comment: ...(continued) So for the example in the question, it does not insert the `<br />`, and if I take away the `<element/>` tag and re-try, it does indert the `<br />` (your proposed solution does not in this latter case).

Comment: You're right, I got the condition wrong. Your latest test should do the trick. Do mind that normalize-space() only normalizes a limited set of space characters (see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#white). If you want to test for all possible whitespace and separators, use `preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][not(replace(., '[\s\p{Z}]+', ''))]` (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#cces for an explanation of the classes in the regex).